# javascript onclick="location.replace('url')" not working

Tags: javascript

i'm writing some inline javascript.  it's not working and i'm not sure why.

at the top of the index page

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />`

later on i have:

```
<select name='id'> 
<option value=-1>New Entry</option> 
<option value='1' onclick="location.replace('index.php?page=update&id=1')">2010-06-12 16:38:08</option> 
<option value='2' onclick="location.replace('index.php?page=update&id=2')">2010-06-12 18:20:49</option> 
<option value='3' onclick="location.replace('index.php?page=update&id=3')">2010-06-13 11:39:09</option> 
</select>
```

what i want is for the page to be replaced when one of the option items is selected but the code is not causing a page refresh and i'm not sure why.  is something wrong with the javascript?

Comment: That seems to work for me in Firefox. I presume you are testing in IE? I'm not sure that supports option.onclick based on here http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/151747-option-onclick-does-not-fire-ie

Comment: was using chrome.  this does work in firefox... didn't realize.  thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event of the `select` element:

```
<select name="id" onchange="window.location.replace('index.php?page=update&id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> 
<option value="-1">New Entry</option> 
<option value="1">2010-06-12 16:38:08</option> 
<option value="2">2010-06-12 18:20:49</option> 
<option value="3">2010-06-13 11:39:09</option> 
</select>
```

Note: The `location.replace` method is used when you want to navigate to the page and also replace the current page in the browsing history. If you just want to navigate to the page normally, you assign the URL to the `window.location.href` property instead.

Comment: @digitalFresh: The `value` property doesn't work in older browsers. I haven't checked recently how old the browser has to be not to support it, but reading the value from the options collection always works.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that `window.location.href` doesn't work at all in newer browsers (FF4, Chrome 10, etc.).